# Packaging an SDL app: will I need multiple projects across platforms?

Tags: cross-platform, sdl, release, packaging

I'm looking into using SDL to build a small cross-platform game.  I'm wondering if when I get to the point of building the game for release, will I need separate projects (say, one for Windows & one for OS X)?  My reason for asking is that Windows installs apps in a hierarchical folder structure (generally under `C:\Program Files`) while OS X installs everything within a `.app` file/folder (generally under `\Applications`).  The way these folder structures differ makes me think I may need 2 different projects, even if most of the underlying code is ultimately shared.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IDEs, such as Visual Studio and Xcode, to build your game, you'll need separate projects. Visual Studio projects can't build Mac applications, and Xcode projects can't build Windows applications.

There are cross-platform build tools, like SCons and CMake, that let you use the same build scripts on Mac and Windows. I can't help you with specifics on using those tools, but you should take a look at them and see whether they would help you.